# startswith operation on python is not working after . character in URL

Tags: python, xml, url

I want to filter the following from tag names of an XML using Python
{http://www.duolog.com/2011/05/socrates}property

If I use the following, the filter is proper

if child.tag.startswith("{http://www."):

But I want to be more specific to include like below which is not filtering properly

if child.tag.startswith("{http://www.d"):

Basically the filter is screwed after the . character

Please help me to fix this

Below is the content of the Python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import re 


tree = ET.parse('COMMON_08.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


searchString = "{http://www.d"

def recurse(node):
    for child in node:
        if child.tag.startswith(searchString):
            print(child.tag)
            #print(child.attrib)
            #print(child.text)
            recurse(child)


node = root.findall(".")
recurse(node)
```

It works if I change the searchString = "{http://www."

I have the same issue with below also

Not working
searchString = "{http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009}f"

Working fine
searchString = "{http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009}"

Comment: Please show your code as well.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Python function is not working properly? Maybe you have typo in your code or tags?

I've tested it using this simple code and it works:

```
>>> s = "{http://www.duolog.com/2011/05/socrates}property"
... if s.startswith("{http://www.d"):
...     print(s)
...     
{http://www.duolog.com/2011/05/socrates}property
```

Comment: Hi Lukas,  Thanks for the reply .I have added more details to the question now

Comment: @user3521633: Yes, you added more details, but you have not posted a [mcve].

Comment: Please add what is actually inside this input file or rewrite your example